# The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, orchardcms

My solution is in Orchard CMS 1.4.1 and when I run the solution then I get the error

`The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController.`
and If I re click the run button then I get this message

`Not found`
`The page you are looking for does not exist.`

Q: Why and how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you please give your codes of route registration here? It seems that something goes wrong when registering the routes.

Comment: Is this a migration from a previous version? Do you see anything in app_data\logs?

Comment: @bertrand-le-roy, ya it is a migration from Orchard 1.2 to 1.4

Comment: Did you run the UpgradeTo14 module on it? You might have to install 1.3 first and then run the upgrade module. See release notes, it's in there.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old thread, but this may help future Googlers (such as myself):

I had a very simple recipe that enabled a few modules and themes. One of the modules provided a "Homepage route" which basically overrode the "/" path to go to a controller within the module. However- once I removed this route, I started getting the same error as the OP.

Turned out that the problem was caused by the fact that I did not have a content page with the homepage property checked (I actually did not have any content pages at all because of the simple recipe).

The solution was to go to /admin (which still worked because the admin controller handles this route) and create a new page with the homepage checkbox ticked.

Comment: I also had this problem **Turned out that the problem was caused by the fact that I did not have a content page with the homepage property checked"**

Answer (score 0):

My answer isn't specific to [orchardcms](/questions/tagged/orchardcms), but may help:

I got this exact same error because I'd added a call to `@Html.Action("Action", "NewController")` into a View without having actually created `NewController` yet!

Perhaps you're missing a Controller?